# jQuery proxy doesn't call async functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I've found that I can't call `async` functions with `$.proxy`. My case was that I proxied event listeners so that they'd still have the same context, but as soon as I tried proxying to an `async` function, it just didn't get called - also, no errors were thrown.

Could anyone explain me why this doesn't work?

The simple example below will allow you to reproduce the issue. When the `async` keyword is there, the function will not be called. When you remove `async`, it'll start working.

```
$('div').on('click', $.proxy(example, this));

async function example() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you use `async` for a function referenced in an event handler, or in this case passed to `$.proxy` to set context and a `this` value, it's not something that is asynchronous. Secondly, why did you think it would work, there's no `await` for the `async` call, which isn't really async? One doesn't have to use `await`, but using `async` the `example` method now returns a promise, and neither `$.proxy` nor the event handler is expecting a promise.

Comment: @adeneo thanks a lot, now I get it - it's my first time jumping into async/await, I missed this detail.

Comment: In this case, `async/await` isn't really needed, there's nothing to wait for, even if there are other asynchronous methods inside `example()`. If that's the case, you can use `async` inside the function, but not when passing it to an event handler, even through `$.proxy`

Comment: Yup, I know that, but it's just a simplified example - in my case, the event handler is marked as `async`, so that's necessary.

Comment: An event handler like that in itself can't be async, it's something that happens when someone does something and triggers an event, so there's no need to "mark" an event handler as "async", just write code the way one usually does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$.proxy` was awesome many years ago. async/await is ES2017, and we already have  `bind` since ES5:

```
$('div').on('click', example.bind(this));
```

So we have async arrows:

```
const example = async () => {
  console.log('test');
}
```

`$.proxy` [uses custom `$.isFunction`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.2.1/src/core.js#L425) check instead of plain `typeof fn === 'function'` check. This results in false negative for native async functions ([transpiled async](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code_lz=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLwgCgJQwDeAvgFBSYjoA2ApgHTXoDmOAJPaiAGJJRqYccCHjxA&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function(config)%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20(var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20(key%20in%20this._config)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20config%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(this._config.debug)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20%5BArray.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%5D%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20(console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20()%20%7B%7D).apply(console%2C%20args)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(this._config.debug)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20%5BArray.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%5D%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20(console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20()%20%7B%7D).apply(console%2C%20args)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch(origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20''%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20(patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply(this%2C%20obj.args.concat(%5Bobj%5D))%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply(this%2C%20obj.args)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(patchFns.post)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug('Postpatched%20%40%20'%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply(this%2C%20obj.args.concat(%5Bobj%5D))%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug('Passed%20%40%20'%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply(this%2C%20obj.args)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20(callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn(obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre(origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post(origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over(origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass(origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork(tree%2C%20context)%20%7B%0A%09%09(function%20process(nodes%2C%20context)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20(var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes%5BnodeName%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context%5BnodeName%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log(%5B'origFn'%2C%20origFn%5D%2C%20%5B'context'%2C%20context%5D%2C%20%5B'nodes'%2C%20nodes%5D%2C%20%5B'nodeName'%2C%20nodeName%5D)%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20(obj)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log('process'%2C%20obj)%0A%09%09%09%09%09process(node.then%2C%20obj.result)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(!('pachted'%20in%20origFn))%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20(node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context%5BnodeName%5D%20%3D%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context%5BnodeName%5D%20%3D%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log(%5B'context%5BnodeName%5D'%2C%20context%5BnodeName%5D%5D%2C%20%5B'nodes%5BnodeName%5D'%2C%20nodes%5BnodeName%5D%5D)%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D)(tree%2C%20context)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D) vs [native async](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code_lz=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLwgCgJQwDeAvgFBSYjoA2ApgHTXoDmOAJPaiAGJJRqYccCHjxA&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function(config)%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20(var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20(key%20in%20this._config)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20config%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(this._config.debug)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20%5BArray.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%5D%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20(console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20()%20%7B%7D).apply(console%2C%20args)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20(this._config.debug)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20%5BArray.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%5D%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20(console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20()%20%7B%7D).apply(console%2C%20args)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch(origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20''%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20(patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply(this%2C%20obj.args.concat(%5Bobj%5D))%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply(this%2C%20obj.args)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(patchFns.post)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug('Postpatched%20%40%20'%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply(this%2C%20obj.args.concat(%5Bobj%5D))%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug('Passed%20%40%20'%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply(this%2C%20obj.args)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20(callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn(obj)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre(origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post(origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over(origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass(origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork(tree%2C%20context)%20%7B%0A%09%09(function%20process(nodes%2C%20context)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20(var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes%5BnodeName%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context%5BnodeName%5D%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log(%5B'origFn'%2C%20origFn%5D%2C%20%5B'context'%2C%20context%5D%2C%20%5B'nodes'%2C%20nodes%5D%2C%20%5B'nodeName'%2C%20nodeName%5D)%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20(obj)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log('process'%2C%20obj)%0A%09%09%09%09%09process(node.then%2C%20obj.result)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20(!('pachted'%20in%20origFn))%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20(node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context%5BnodeName%5D%20%3D%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context%5BnodeName%5D%20%3D%20this.patch(origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log(%5B'context%5BnodeName%5D'%2C%20context%5BnodeName%5D%5D%2C%20%5B'nodes%5BnodeName%5D'%2C%20nodes%5BnodeName%5D%5D)%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D)(tree%2C%20context)%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D)). This results from the fact that native async functions are instances of [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction), not `Function` directly.

This is another reason why jQuery shouldn't always be used just because it can. jQuery helper functions were indispensable when there were no native alternatives or they were flaky - but aren't anymore.